# Is M2x2 a subpace of itself?

Tags: vector-spaces, invariant-subspace

Prove that the set $B = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} | a,b,c,d ∈ \mathbb{Z}\right\}$ is not a subspace of
$M(2,2)$.

Comment: What is the definition of $M(2,2)$? You might also want to think about the definition of a subspace. Make more effort and edit the question to show what you did. That might help it get reopened.

Answer (score 1):

If you take an element of $B$ and multiply it by a scalar, it must yield another element of $B$. What happens if you choose the scalar to be $\sqrt{2}$?